# Twitter API v1.1. Abraham library: no redirection after signing in

Tags: php, twitter, callback

I am using the abraham library to sign in with twitter on my website.

I have done many tutorials and I don't understand why the callback url is never called.

The file "login.php" correctly displays the twitter authentication form. Clicking on "Sign in" only redirects to https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate.
However when I click on "Cancel" it redirects to the specified callback file.

I gave a callback url to the method "getRequestToken" and set the same url in the application settings on the twitter dev website. I have set the application access as "Read only" and checked "Allow this application to be used to Sign in with Twitter".

This is my files:

login.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("twitter-config.php");

include_once("lib/twitteroauth-master/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php");


$connection = new TwitterOAuth($CONSUMER_KEY, $CONSUMER_SECRET);
$request_token = $connection->getRequestToken($OAUTH_CALLBACK); //get Request Token


if( $request_token)
{
    $token = $request_token['oauth_token'];
    $_SESSION['request_token'] = $token ;
    $_SESSION['request_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];


    switch ($connection->http_code) 
    {
        case 200:
            $url = $connection->getAuthorizeURL($token);
            //redirect to Twitter .
            header('Location: ' . $url); 
            break;
        default:
          print_r($connection->http_info);
            echo "<br/>Connection with twitter Failed<br/><br/> Date du serveur:" . date("M d Y H:i:s", time()) . " <br/> Date de Twitter: " . $connection->http_header['date'];
            break;
    }

}
else //error receiving request token
{
    echo "Error Receiving Request Token";
}
?>
```

twitter-config.php:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * A single location to store configuration.
 */

$CONSUMER_KEY = 'XXXXXXX';
$CONSUMER_SECRET = 'XXXXXXX';
$OAUTH_CALLBACK = 'https://www.xxxxx.com/preprod/users/twitter-signin/oauth.php';

?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it was a problem with twitter dev: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/21599